# SSL installed but HTTPS prefix not always present on address bar

Tags: ssl, https

SSL certificate was succesfully installed on the server.

I assume the installation was succesfull because when I type my domain including the https prefix, the browser will actually show the green lock. However, this only happens when the https is typed... if I type mydomain.com or www.mydomain.com, the address bar does not show https or the green lock.

How could accomplish to always show the https prefix??

Thank's in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

You need to force a redirect from all HTTP requests to HTTPS.

From: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName mysite.example.com
   DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
   Redirect permanent /secure https://mysite.example.com/secure
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
   ServerName mysite.example.com
   DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
   SSLEngine On
# etc...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thank you, for some reason those configurations don't accomplish the objetive... the browser doesn't redirect. Do you place that text only in one virtualhost?? or you place one part in 80 and the other in 443?? ... I have tried both ways and when I place it all in 80, apache presents errors. I ended up doing the job by using mod_rewrite... which was in the same website that you linked. Not the most proper solution, but  it's something for now :S

Comment: The only configuration you need is the **Redirect permanent**.  Put that in the VirtualHost configuration of the HTTP or port 80 server.  That will cause all requests for HTTP to go to the HTTPS virtual host.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to redirect traffic from http://example.com and http://www.example.com to HTTPS. The method will vary depending on the webserver you use. A search in Google for "redirect http to https [webserver]" will give you several guides to set this up.

Comment: can't vote up yet, but thxs ;). still can't fix the whole thing, but that exact search took me into other topics that were very useful.